# Groupby and string-concatenate multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like so:

```
ID  CODE  GROUP  PIN
 1   99     A     221
 1   89     B     443
 2   79     A     230
 2   69     A     000
 3   59     D     781
 3   49     T     665
```

I want to groupby the ID column and string-concatenate all the other fields, comma-separated, so I get output like so:

```
 ID  CODE     GROUP      PIN
 1   99,89     A,B     221,443
 2   79,69     A,A     230,000
 3   59,49     D,T     781,665
```

I can `groupby` the ID and return the CODE field concatenated but I need to do that for more than just one field:

```
df = DATA.groupby('ID')['CODE'].apply(',' .join).reset_index(drop = False)
```

This returns just the grouped ID field and a concatenated CODE field. How can I expand the groupby to multiple columns?

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If want avoid convert `ID` to strings use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), convert all columns to strings and use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) for processing each column separately:

```
df = DATA.set_index('ID').astype(str).groupby('ID').agg(',' .join).reset_index()
print (df)
   ID   CODE GROUP      PIN
0   1  99,89   A,B  221,443
1   2  79,69   A,A    230,0
2   3  59,49   D,T  781,665

print (df.dtypes)
ID        int64
CODE     object
GROUP    object
PIN      object
dtype: object
```

If `ID` are strings or possible convert to strings:

```
df = DATA.astype(str).groupby('ID').agg(',' .join).reset_index()
print (df)
  ID   CODE GROUP      PIN
0  1  99,89   A,B  221,443
1  2  79,69   A,A    230,0
2  3  59,49   D,T  781,665

print (df.dtypes)
ID       object
CODE     object
GROUP    object
PIN      object
dtype: object
```